# webkitRequestFullscreen works, but pops right back

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkitrequestfullscreen

I'm trying to implement a button that will make the page go full screen.

When clicking the button, the page goes full screen but only for a split second **and then it pops right back** to the way it was. There are no errors in the browser console (via Chrome).

Here's my JS code:

```
function enterFullscreen() {
   var elem = document.getElementById('parent');
   if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
   }
   else {
        if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
        else {
            elem.requestFullscreen();
        }
   }
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <button onclick="enterFullscreen()">Toggle fullscreen</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem... I needed to add `return false;` in the button click event:

```
<button onclick="enterFullscreen(); return false;">Toggle fullscreen</button>
```